# IE v. FF: Is table.tBodies[0] valid?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

From what I gather, tBodies[0] seems to work in IE, but not FF.  Is this an IE mistake?  I've created a small file to demonstrate the incosistency, and I would like to know the best way to go about this.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
 <table id="dataGrid">
 </table>
 <input type="button" onclick="insertRow();" value="New row">
</body>
</html>
```

This script should add a row every time the button is clicked.  It works in IE but breaks in Firefox:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/costplan/script/prototype.js"></script>
<script>    
function insertRow(){
 var objTbl = $('dataGrid').tBodies[0]; 
 lastRow = objTbl.rows.length;
 alert(lastRow);
 var newRow = objTbl.insertRow(lastRow);
}
</script>
```

Is tBodies[0] invalid?  I'm not sure why, but this code works in both FF and IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/costplan/script/prototype.js"></script>
<script>
function insertRow(){
 var objTbl = $('dataGrid');
 lastRow = objTbl.rows.length;
 alert(lastRow);
 var newRow = objTbl.insertRow(lastRow);
}    
</script>
```

Are either of these functions correct?  Basically, I don't really know what's going on (I gather that at least one of these scripts is invalid, but I don't know which or why).

Comment: You're using Prototype, right?

Comment: Also, it's a good be that the one that works is the one that's valid.

Comment: Correct.  As far as I know, it only matters for the $ function.

Comment: i don't know prototype, but why in jquery you could do `$('dataGrid tbody:first')`

Comment: @Pointy I had guessed so, but I wanted to be sure and hopefully understand why the other one is invalid. It seems like tBodies[0].rows should work out for me.

Comment: You can always check the MDC (Mozilla Developers Connection) website and see what the "table" DOM element supports. I doubt that "tBodies" is a w3c standard.

Answer (score 4):

The [`tBodies`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63206416) property is part of the DOM Level 2 standard, and it [works](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html) on both browsers.

The difference you are having is that IE *always* injects a `TBODY` element as a child of your empty table.

Firefox, Chrome and other browsers don't do it if the element is empty, if the `TABLE` element has at least one `TR` or `TH`, they will create the `TBODY` implicitly.

You could add the `TBODY` element by yourself, and your [example](http://jsbin.com/ucuke4) will work without problems:

```
<table id="dataGrid">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```