# How to force a tbody element into an empty table for non IE browsers

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

I have a pretty complex implementation of an old infragistics UltraWebGrid. Which I am trying to force into browser compatability, even though they just tell me to upgrade. My grid is not rendering rows for a certain grid for non IE browsers. I have traced the error to some built in javascript which I will add below. I think I can force the grid to work by adding a tbody element to the grids html table before It attempts to render the dynamically added rows. My logic for coming across this idea is below. How would I go about doing this?

As per [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817832/ie-v-ff-is-table-tbodies0-valid), only IE automatically ads a tbody element to an empty table. Other browsers require at least one row for a tbody element to exist. The javascript error that seems to be preventing this grid from rendering is the inability to get the tbody element of the main grid table. This should be able to be fixed by forcing a tbody element in the table via javascript if the browser is anything other than IE.

The old infragistics grid's built in javascript seems to assume this tbody element will be there in an empty grid. Because of this, my page is unable to load the rows of the grid in non IE browsers because the javascript is calling an element that doesnt exist.

Breaking javascript:

(this breaks at the last line for non IE browsers. I assume because there is no tbody element)

```
var strTransform = this.applyXslToNode(this.Node);
if (strTransform)
{
    var anId = (this.AddNewRow ? this.AddNewRow.Id : null);
    this.Grid._innerObj.innerHTML = "<table style=\"table-layout:fixed;\">" + strTransform + "</table>";
    var tbl = this.Element.parentNode;
    igtbl_replaceChild(tbl, this.Grid._innerObj.firstChild.firstChild, this.Element);
    igtbl_fixDOEXml();
    var _b = this.Band;
    var headerDiv = igtbl_getElementById(this.Grid.Id + "_hdiv");
    var footerDiv = igtbl_getElementById(this.Grid.Id + "_fdiv");
    if (this.AddNewRow)
    {
        if (_b.Index > 0 || _b.AddNewRowView == 1 && !headerDiv || _b.AddNewRowView == 2 && !footerDiv)
        {
            var anr = this.AddNewRow.Element;
            anr.parentNode.removeChild(anr);
            if (_b.AddNewRowView == 1 && tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length > 0)
                tbl.tBodies[0].insertBefore(anr, tbl.tBodies[0].rows[0]);
            else
                tbl.tBodies[0].appendChild(anr);
        }
        this.AddNewRow.Element = igtbl_getElementById(anId);
        this.AddNewRow.Element.Object = this.AddNewRow;
    }
    this.Element = tbl.tBodies[0];
    this.Element.Object = this;
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the beginning to this.Grid._innerObj.innerHTML = "<table style=\"table-layout:fixed;\"><tbody>" + strTransform + "</tbody></table>" ?

Comment: It does appear as if that would be the best spot to do it. So I should be able to override this compiled javascript? Its all ScripResourced out of the 3rd party control.

Comment: Yes, setting innerHTML creates HTML in your web page.  If strTransform already contains a tbody, you can skip adding one, and if not, you can add one by changing strTransform.

Comment: I am pretty decent with javascript, but havnt done anything like this before. the compiles js looks like its adding a bunch of functions to an object type as an api of sorts. formatted like ~~ var igtbl_ptsBand = ["functionname1",function(){...},"functionname2",function(){...},... and so on. How would I override this? SHould i make a new question?

Comment: For that part I would make a new question, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding the tbody when you set innerHTML at the top.  Check if strTransform already contains a tbody, and if it doesn't, add one yourself.  Something like:

```
var tadd1 = '';
var tadd2 = '';
if (!(/\<tbody\>/.test(strTransform))) {
    tadd1 = '<tbody>';
    tadd2 = '</tbody>';
}
this.Grid._innerObj.innerHTML =
    "<table style=\"table-layout:fixed;\">" + tadd1 + strTransform + tadd2 + "</table>";
```

Comment: That definitely looks like the answer to my question... i just need to know how to override/replace this code. I know its possible, i just have not done it, or know how.

Comment: @jumpdart, I will check for your question on the override.  (We'll need a little more info about how the object is constructed and what you have access to, to answer that part).